# What is the best version of ngTagsInput for Angular not AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-tags-input, ngx-chips

I found the ngTagsInput framework

https://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

a very feature-rich library. But for Angular 8 users I found the ngx-chips framework

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips

It appears to work, but appears to be missing some obvious features, or it the features are achievable they appear to be difficult to implement.  For example: providing chips of different colors.

Questions:

1) Is ngx-chips the most capable replacement for ngTagsInput for the Angular 2+? is there something better?

2) I understand it's not recommended to use a angularjs library inside of Angular 2+? So using the ngTagsInput library can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngx-chips was the best opensource framework I found at this time.  Documentation is a bit terse, but the software is self appears solid.